# Adding red border to invalid input fields using client-side HTML5 validation and Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

With this message on the Bootstrap 5.2 validation documentation,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/

> "We are aware that currently the client-side custom validation styles and tooltips are not accessible, since they are not exposed to assistive technologies. While we work on a solution, we’d recommend either using the server-side option or the default browser validation method.",

I'm looking for another way to style invalid input fields with a red border. So I tried the HTML5 approach and can't get a red border to appear. I used to do this with ease using Bootstrap 3.3.7, but for some reason, years later, I can't seem to get it to work with Bootstrap 5.2 (or without any framework).

```
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Favorite fruit with required attribute</title>
    <style>
        input:valid {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
        
        input:invalid {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        
        input:invalid:required {
            background-color: #d2d2d2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="choose1">What is your favorite color?</label>
            <input id="choose1" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="choose2">What is your favorite breakfast food?</label>
            <input id="choose2" required>
        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Favorite fruit with required attribute</title>
    <style>
        input:valid {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }
        
        input:invalid {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        
        input:invalid:required {
            background-color: #d2d2d2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="choose1">What is your favorite color?</label>
            <input id="choose1" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="choose2">What is your favorite breakfast food?</label>
            <input id="choose2" required>
        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, I have just run it and cannot see a problem. The empty inputs do have red borders. Perhaps you could add a bit more explanation and a snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: I added a snippet to the original post, but still see it showing the red border by default and changing to black on Submit. I need it to show red border on submit if the field is invalid (left empty).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's Javascript. if you don't need to send anything from the `form`, remove the `type="submit"` from the button and in the `addEventListener` change "submit" to "click".

```js
//When the DOM is loaded, apply this
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
//Get the form ID
  const form = document.getElementById("formm");
  //on submit form, check if valid
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.classList.add("was-validated");
  })
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Favorite fruit with required attribute</title>
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<!--add an ID and "novalidate" to disable the alert from browser-->
    <form id="formm" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="choose1">What is your favorite color?</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="choose1" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="choose2">What is your favorite breakfast food?</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="choose2" required>
        </div>
        <!--add button type to submit-->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!--Just Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question. What do you mean by this: "if you don't need to send anything from the form"? I'm creating a contact us form so we'll need to capture form submissions.

Comment: @linnse I understand, in that case then the code I put is fine for what you need. Many times some people use the forms as wizards and then display for example, a modal.
the `preventDefault` in the Javascript code prevents the form from being submitted if the inputs are not filled in.